# WebView Error In Android Deployed Device

Tags: java, android, html, webview, intellij-idea

I have an html file that runs perfectly in the emulator but doesn't work in the deployed Android device.

This is my code in XML of the layout that has the WebView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/white_paper_complete">

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/wv_basicinfo" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:text="       BASIC INFORMATION"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/loader"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code in its class:

```
package com.example.ITax;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class OpenBasicInfo extends MyActivity
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_info);

    WebView wv_basic_info = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_basicinfo);
    wv_basic_info.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.basicinfo), "html", "utf-8");
}

private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID)
{
    InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;

    try
    {
         i = raw.read();
        while(i != -1)
        {
            stream.write(i);
            i = raw.read() ;
        }
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stream.toString();
}
}
```

My html file that is located in res > raw > basicinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

```
wv_basic_info.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.basicinfo), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

This works flawlessly, especially on Android 4.0, which apparently ignores character encoding inside HTML.

Tested on 2.3 and 4.0.3.

Comment: I already tried this, but still doesn't work on the device :(

Answer (score 0):

Is GPU rendering enabled? WebView is not supported when GPU rendering is enabled (this may just be for the emulator)
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

> **Note**: Not all applications are compatible with graphics hardware acceleration. In particular, the Browser application and applications using the WebView component are not compatible with graphics acceleration.

Comment: hmm the application is working perfectly in the emulator, but not on the device..